# Changing stepsize in odeint or predefining a method to solve the differential equation instead of using the adaptive algorithm

Tags: python, scipy

Is there some way we could manually change the step size (use a certain method) in odeint instead of using the adaptive stepsize algorithm that it has inbuilt. I just want to test if odeint is working fine with my differential equation by checking it with different predefined stepsizes

I have tried changing the maximum and minimum stepsize control parameters.

Vx = odeint(action_potential,V0,T)

I just want to verify if this method solves the ode using different stepsizes to be sure that the problem is correctly getting solved

Comment: odeint is a wrapper for the venerable LSODA solver.  Given this, it should be first assumed that LSODA is working correctly and that your code is incorrect.  LSODA is inherently an adaptive step size algorithm, although I think you could get it to be fixed step size if you tune it just right.  Given the 'action_potential' function, I suspect you may have discontinuities in your function.  If my suspicion is true, you could look into the 'tcrit' setting in LSODA, i.e. rwork(1), which can be used to make sure LSODA does not miss the discontinuity.

Comment: If instead you are trying to validate the odeint wrapper, you should compare it head to head with the fortran version.